# Flickering problem when displaying a video stream from webcam in a GUI label

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, label, customtkinter

I am using a customtkinter package in python to create a UI for streaming live videos from webcam. I have multiple cameras and I created a tabview of labels so that I can display multiple videos simultaneusly. I was able to do this with OpenCV, however, the videos displayed are flickering. I used the after() method and the flickering was solved but I can only display one video so Im using a while loop instead with time.sleep() at the end of the block. I am using multithreading for each camera source that are capturing and displaying frames in each ctklabel. Each threads are daemon threads that are looping infinitely, and each of those threads are updating their respective labels. What could be the cause of the flickering?

I want to fix the flickering display of live feeds without affecting the main thread.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.